# Redirect stderr to Logger instance

Tags: ruby, stderr

I have a [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) instance:

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new( 'foo.log', 'weekly' )
```

I want to redirect runtime errors (stderr output) into the log as well. I found [this forum thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/201447) which has the advice:

```
new_fd = logger.get_logger_file_descriptor
$stderr.reopen new_fd
```

However, Logger does not have an instance method `get_logger_file_descriptor`, nor can I find any exposed methods around gaining access to the log device or file.

How can I cause all $stderr output to go into the log?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're creating the logger yourself, you can create the `File` object first, then use it to create the logger and assign it to `$stderr`:

```ruby
log_file = File.new('foo.log', 'a')
logger = Logger.new(log_file, 'weekly')
$stderr = log_file   #usually no need to use reopen
```

Note that this will result in the log output being mixed up with the output of `$stderr`, which may cause problems if you're parsing the log file expecting it to be in a certain format (this will happen with your solution too).

If you don't have the underlying file but just receive the `logger` from somewhere else, it's a bit more tricky. What is needed is an `IO` like object that can be assigned to `$stderr` and passes anything written to it to the logger. The `IO` class in Ruby is unfortunately fairly closely tied to the underlying i/o system (file descriptors and the like), and there's no general interface that can be used to create input and output streams. (`StringIO` being the notable exception).

However most, if not all, of the output methods on `IO` ultimately go through `#write`, so by overriding this one method you can get close to what you're after:

```ruby
class IOToLog < IO

  def initialize(logger)
    @logger = logger
  end

  def write(string)
    #assume anything written to stderr is an error
    @logger.error(message)
  end

end

logger = get_logger_from_somewhere

$stderr = IOToLog.new(logger)
```

Now anything written to `$stderr` will end up going to the log file. The formatting however will be a bit odd. Anytime any of the writing methods calls `#write` a new entry will be made in the logfile. For example, `#puts` called with an array will call `#write` for each entry of the array, and again with a newline character between each entry, resulting in 2n - 1 log entries, n - 1 of which will be blank.

You could make the overridden `#write` method more complex to handle this, perhaps using an internal buffer, and only call the logger when you think you have a full message. Alternatively you could override the individual methods to write to the logger themselves. If you did this the `IOToLog` class wouldn't necessarily have to inherit from `IO`.

Your best solution will depend on how you want to standard error output to appear in the logfile, how your program uses `$stderr`, and how much work you want to do implementing methods from `IO`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! In my case I am creating the logger so your first solution is clean and elegant. I particularly like that you've included the workaround for the other case. (Though in such a case I might advocate my hack of reaching in and grabbing the file directly.)

Comment: The second method doesn't work for me on jruby. I get the following error: (Errno::EBADF) Bad file descriptor

Answer (score 2):

The best I've been able to come up with is this reach-around hack:

```
$stderr.reopen logger.instance_variable_get(:@logdev).dev
```

It works, but of course breaks the encapsulation of Logger which I assume was there for a reason.